# Do hours flying "advanced ultralight" aircraft contribute towards your license in Canada?

Tags: ultralight, canada, transport-canada, cpl

I'm interested in the business possibilities of offering flight training in Southern Ontario, in particular using advanced ultralight aircraft. I realize that this is uncommon, of course, but my question is one of regulations.

How many hours flying an advanced ultralight aircraft can count towards a student's:

- Recreational license?
- Personal license?
- Commercial license?

I'm not sure how to read the [CARs here in 421](https://tc.canada.ca/en/corporate-services/acts-regulations/list-regulations/canadian-aviation-regulations-sor-96-433/standards/standard-421-flight-crew-permits-licences-ratings-canadian-aviation-regulations-cars). Would a Pipistrel Alpha Electro (classified as an Advanced Ultralight in Canada) or Pipistrel Velis count as "aeroplane"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can count the flight hours towards a recreational license if you logged the hours in an advanced ultralight with an aeroplane certificate of airworthiness.

For the private pilot license only 10 hours in three-axis ultralights can be counted.

For a commercial ticket a maximum of 25 hours pilot-in-command flight time in three axis ultra-light aeroplanes can be counted towards the 200 hours total flight time requirement but this time does not count towards the 100 hour pilot-in-command flight time.

This is based on my cursory reading of the requirements. I would suggest you talk to a reputable flight training organization or Canadian aviation authorities for confirmation.